# JUnit using a h2 in memory database does not work having "ARRAY" function in SQL

Tags: java, postgresql, junit, h2

I am trying to write some unit tests using a h2 in memory database. The database in production is a postgresql. So, having a postgresql database, the SQL contains "ARRAY" function. When i try to unit test that sql result using h2, i receive the error that "ARRAY" function does not exist.

SQL:

```
"select DISTINCT(R.id), T.id, T.authorid, T.authorname, T.enddate, T.operationType, R.imsicount, t.isallimsis,"
                    + "    array(select deviceip from wm_audit_device where audittrailid = T.id and success = true  ) as successdevices,"
                    + "    array(select deviceip from wm_audit_device where audittrailid = T.id and success = false  ) as faileddevices";
```

Actul results:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "ARRAY" not found; SQL statement:
```

There is an workaround for keep testing this result?

Comment: unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list. Putting a single column between parentheses won't change anything. `distinct (a),b,c´ is exactly the same as `distinct a,(b),c` or  `distinct a,b,c`

Comment: doesn't matter...my problem is with ARRAY function

Comment: Perhaps create _array_ as an [H2 user defined function](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem where i had to get a `postgresql` custom function tested in H2. Seems like the basics of my solution would work for this use case as well.

Add the MockResultSet class found at https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/09/java-mocking-resultset-using-mockito.html into your test classes.

Create a utility class with a static method `array` that returns a `ResultSet`.

```
public class H2TestFunctionUtility {
  public static ResultSet array() {
    // build your mocked result here
    String[] columnNames = new String[] {"column", "names", "here"};
    Object[][] rowValues = new Object[][] { {"values"}, {"go"},  {"here"}}; 
    return MockResultSet.create(columnNames, rowValues); //
  }
}
```

Create an SQL script to register the function with `H2`

```
CREATE ALIAS array FOR "com.example.my.test.utility.package.TestUtility.array";
```

Annotate the test method (or class if appropriate) with:

```
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:my-function-registration-script.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
```

Test(s) should run.

Comment: I understand, but if you look at my SQL, i am using array function for having different  values between (). First, i have a boolean false and second i have a boolean true

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider also using [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) which provide `PostgreSQLContainer`. Instead of using H2 in memory you can use configuration which will be more consistent with your production environment.

Sample of usage you can find [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/jdbc-test/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/junit/SimplePostgreSQLTest.java).